# Is there a good way to shorten time to Export many pictures?

Tags: image-processing

I want to export many PNG pictures using Mathematica. However, it takes too much time.
To make matters worse, sometimes it suddenly aborts. With any pictures, I have same problem.

For example, I `Import` about 1000 pictures of 2000x2000 pixels as "imagelist" and then each of them are divided into 20x20 pixels using:

```
part = ImagePartition[#, 20] & /@ imagelist;
data= Flatten[part]
```

There are now 10000 pictures.

```
namelist =  StringJoin["/Users/Documents/no", ToString[#], ".png"]&/@Range[10000]
```

Then I try to export:

```
Export[namelist[[#]],data[[#]]]&/@Range[10000]
```

If the number of Picture is hundreds, the above works. However, if the number is more than several thousands, it stops or becomes too slow.

Comment: You should not load so many images into Mathematica as you will quickly exceed all available memory. 1000 2000x2000 RGB(A) images requires 1000*2000*2000*4 bytes, when the PNGs are decompressed (about 15GB!). Instead, consider out-of-core methods, or `Import`  and `Export` in a  `Do` loop. If you do this first, you can then look into a `ParallelDo` to batch process them.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!! I tried your code, and found it really fast. Also thank you for your kind guidance. Until then, I struggled many times.Therefore, I'm so grateful to you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this, and avoid loading everything into memory at once:

```
processImage[imgfile_] := 
 Module[{img, parts, i = 0, base = FileBaseName[imgfile]},
  img = Import[imgfile, "PNG"];
  parts = Flatten[ImagePartition[img, 20]];
  i = 0;
  Do[
   With[{path = 
      StringTemplate["/Users/Documents/`b`_`n`.png"][<|"b" -> base, "n" -> i|>]},
    Export[path, p];
    ];
   ++i;
   , {p, parts}
   ]
  ]

imagefiles = {"test1.png", "test2.png"};
ParallelDo[
 processImage[imgfile]
 , {imgfile, imagefiles}
 ]
```